# Visual studio will not open my .sln project

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I am trying to open a .sln project, but it's giving me a migration report with 1 error. It says "The application which this project type is based on was not found." I've tried to reload the project in the 'Solution Explorer'. Does anyone know how to open it?

Comment: Open the .sln file with a text editor (notepad, notepad++, textpad, etc) and look for the line(s) that start with `Project` i.e. `Project("{GUID}") = "SO_Trash", "SO_Trash\SO_Trash.dtproj"` That says relative to the current folder, go down into SO_Trash and open the project file SO_Trash.dtproj (which is an SSIS project type) so you'll need to figure out what is the application type being referenced and then do you have the associated project types installed.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: There was "incompatible" in brackets next to the project on visual studio. I googled it, the answer from Google which solved it was "By right clicking on project and reload it solved the issue. The issue is caused by IS extension is disabled. Please navigate to Tools > Extensions and updates, search for "Microsoft Integration Services Projects" and enable it."